# Laravel Model Show Function returning null

Tags: laravel, binding, model, resources

I have an installation of Laravel 5.6 and have setup multiple authentication.

All is working except when I go into a resource show function the eloquent is not getting the record. Just returning null.

I have search on Google for 2 days and just can't figure it out.

Code as follows.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/user/logout','Auth\LoginController@userLogout')->name('user.logout');

//admin route for our multi-auth system

Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('login.submit');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    //admin password reset routes
    Route::post('/password/email','Auth\AdminForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('/password/reset','Auth\AdminForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('/password/reset','Auth\AdminResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','Auth\AdminResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');

});

Route::resource('/admin/stock_categories','Admin\Stock\CategoryController');
```

The resource I am working with is the stock_categories above.

My routes:list is as follows.

```
|        | POST      | admin/stock_categories                       | stock_categories.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@store                   | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stock_categories                       | stock_categories.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@index                   | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stock_categories/create                | stock_categories.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@create                  | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stock_categories/{stock_category}      | stock_categories.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@show                    | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/stock_categories/{stock_category}      | stock_categories.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@update                  | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | DELETE    | admin/stock_categories/{stock_category}      | stock_categories.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@destroy                 | web,auth:admin                               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/stock_categories/{stock_category}/edit | stock_categories.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Stock\CategoryController@edit                    | web,auth:admin
```

When I show the list it appears correctly.

But when I click into an item and open the URL

```
/admin/stock_categories/1
```

It returns an empty result. I.e doesn't show the item.

My model code is as follows.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class Category extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'stock_categories';
    //protected $fillable = ['name, discount'];

    //
    function items() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Item','category_id');
    }

}
```

My controller is code is as follows.

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}


/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $category = Category::where('master_category_id',0)->orderBy('name')->paginate(20);
    $master_category_id = 0;
    return view('admin.stock.top_list',compact('category','master_category_id'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Category  $category
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */


public function show(Category $category)
{
    return view('admin.stock.category',compact('category'));
}
```

When I var_dump($category) inside the show function I get this.

```
object(App\Category)#755 (26) {
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(16) "stock_categories"
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["withCount":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["changes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
}
```

My middleware looks like this.

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

I am hoping that there is just something stupid that I have done and for the life of me I cannot find.

So to summarise, I click on an item, load the show resource route but the item is not retrieved from the database.

Any help with be greatly apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you verified that the control reaches inside of your `show` method?

Comment: Yes, I can return a view from the show method, but the $category is as per the var_dump. So yes, in the show method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look for `Model Binding`.
Some resources here, that shows how to pass Model object to Controller.

1. [Route model binding documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding)
2. [Some examples](https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding)
3. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578137/laravel-resource-controllers-routes-and-models)

I hope that help you find some clues.

Comment: Thanks, it is the model binding I am expecting to be happening here. I will look through the example page in more detail. The explicit example is pretty much exactly what I had coded here. Thanks

Comment: This is why I thought it might be something up with my authentication and model bindings in Kernel.php.

Comment: I updated answer, see `3` link, your route has ` admin/stock_categories/{stock_category}` but controller accepts `$category`.

Comment: Hi, yes thanks this sorted me out. Thanks a million.!

Comment: This helped me.thanks a lot. but im still very confused why the variable name matters

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the id sent in your route to fetch the category.

eg.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);

    return view('admin.stock.category',compact('category'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, that works if I hard code the ID, but the $id which in my case is (Category $category) doesn't contain the ID from the url.

Comment: I don't think the resource method ```show``` was ever going to provide an automatically loaded record. Here is some more info from the docs about resource controllers https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: That's the point, you need to change the argument in the show method to an integer eg ```$id``` then use it to retrieve the record.

Comment: OK, I thought because laravel automatically generated the method with (Category $category) that eloquent was going to automatically retrieve the record. Thanks

Comment: I have no issue with eloquent retrieving the record by passing in an ID and letting laravel return the listed model; in this case passing `1` as the id to a method accepting `Category $category`. I get back a `Category` model as expected. 
However, as soon as I add `auth:api` to my middleware the model binding is broken and everything is null for the same example. Sounds just like the same issue as the OP.